# List flight prices to different cities for specific dates?

Tags: usa, air-travel, flight-search-engines, domestic-travel

I want to visit another US city for a few days at the end of October. I'm open to visiting any city and flying in any airline, as long as it's relatively inexpensive and it's non-stop.

Let's say I'm departing from Miami, is there a way to see a list of prices from Miami to other cities in the US?

For example:

```
 MIA -> JFK : $220
 MIA -> BOS : $185
 MIA -> DAL : $240
 MIA -> ATL : $320
```

If that were the list, then it'd be Boston.

Comment: you can try using Google Flights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I'm departing from Miami, is there a way to see a list of prices from Miami to other cities in the US?

Google Flights:

[image]

[Kiwi](https://www.kiwi.com/en/search/tiles/seattle-washington-united-states/united-states/2022-10-21/2022-10-25?sortAggregateBy=price):

[image]

Comment: interesting (as always) to see how prices are so weakly correlated with actual distance flown.

Comment: Within reason that indeed matters less. When you go so far it's worth switching from narrowbody to widebody you will see the price jump.

Comment: I think Southwest doesn't show up on these sites, right? That might be worth checking separately.

Comment: At least in Google Flights, it only displays the most popular destinations.

Comment: Your Google Flights screenshot doesn't show prices to Las Vegas, Salt Lake City, Santa Fe, Dallas, etc.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf scroll down in the flight list or zoom in in the map